# cards lose their position when on new line in ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, col

I am looping thru items with ng-repeat. Here is the code:

```
<div class="row"
<div class="w3-card-3 col-xs-18 col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="p in products">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img ng-src="{{p.img}}" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="text-danger">{{p.brand}}</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p>

            <a  href="car/{{ p.id }}"  class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
            </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Info</a>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button">Bid</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when the repeater enters a new line the cards generated gets messed up. Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

What's wrong with my code? Why won't the cards align underneath each other. Tell me if there is anything else you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use height of image and description wrapper it should solve the problem

Comment: height of image didt it, Should i use em or px for best practice?

Comment: as you wish. both will give the height. but i will use in px

Answer (score 0):

Try to add *style="float: left"* in the div below:

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="float: left">
```

Comment: the cards didnt move, sorry